# Reduce height and vertical padding for a react-native-paper TextInput

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, react-native, expo

I have the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Button, TextInput } from 'react-native-paper';

export default class Header extends Component {

  state = {
    text: '',
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput value={this.state.text} style={styles.input} />
        <Button mode="contained" style={styles.button}>Add Todo</Button>
      </View>
    );
  }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    backgroundColor: '#c1deff',
  },
  input: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  button: {
    flex: 0,
  },
});
```

which outputs the following screen:

[image]

**My goal is** to reduce the height for the `TextInput`. It also looks like it has some vertical padding. Is it possible to decrease that as well? I'm just trying to save space on the screen and in my opinion is taking lot of it area.

**EDIT 01**

I tried with the following style:

```
input: {
  flex: 1,
  height: 40,
  borderColor: 'gray',
  borderWidth: 1,
}
```

but didn't work, because I got the following result:

[image]

which as you can see, doesn't look good (obvious).

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

add `height` and `justifyContent` in style

```
input: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 40,
    justifyContent:"center"
}
```

Comment: That's a life saving thing! anything isn't working `padding, margin, paddingHorizontal, paddingVertical` Nothing but this :/ set height to save your life as well

Answer (score 2):

You can set height for it if you want:

```
<TextInput
    style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, justifyContent:"center"}}
     onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
    value={this.state.text}
  />
```

Source: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput

Also try searching in Github for some custom inputtext. They may have what you need. Good luck!

Comment: tried that with no success. Please, check my **Edit 01**

Comment: @davidesp edited. Sry i dont have access to laptop right now and im on my phone :) i cant test any code right now to give you sure answer

Comment: no probs @Amas, this question is now solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

use `margin` with negative value like

```
contentStyle={{ marginHorizontal: -10, marginVertical: -2 }}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

As you can see from the source code, you can only change the input size by modifying the render prop

Answer (score 0):

To adjust the height add the style `height: 40` and to adjust vertical padding add the style `paddingHorizontal: 0`

Your tag should then look like the following:

```
<TextInput value={"Something"} style={{ flex: 1, height: 40, paddingHorizontal: 0}} />
```